# the program can't start because msvcr100.dll is missing

Tags: php, c++, visual-studio

I was working on a symfony project and my current wamp wasn't good enough (PHP version to low) so I downloaded the latest version of wamp and had trouble installing it.

I read the notice before downloading that I had to install 'Visual C++ Redistributable ...'

[image]

But still I recieve the error `the program can't start because msvcr100.dll is missing`

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: You installed the VC 2012 redist. The error reports the VC **2010** redist is missing. Install the correct runtime and try again.

Comment: I did but I still get the error

Comment: Great, now is the winamp you're using x64 or x86 ? (there are *two* distinct redist packages for vs2010; more if you include the service packs).

Comment: 64-bit and service pack 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there was a problem with the laptop. I tried reinstalling everything and still nothing (I mean windows reset). I then (if I remember correctly) did the same installation on another laptop and it worked without a problem so i have no clue what the problem really was and never got it fixed.

But I ended up buying a macbook pro and gave that windows laptop to someone else. So this issue wasn't really resolved but I like I said, it was probably a problem with the laptop itself.

Answer (score 1):

Install both x64 and x86 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Path" system variable contains the location of the dll. An easy way to check it is by opening Prompt Command and typing the name of the dll - if the system finds the dll the Path contains a reference to it, if not you should add it in the Path.
Also make sure that the dll version that the system finds is the the correct version - X64 or X86, if not just change the Path.